# How does the Android Lock Screen Camera work

Tags: android, android-widget, android-camera, lockscreen

In Android 4.2 new lock screen widget have been introduced. They can be accessed by sliding left or right on the lock screen.

One of those widgets is a camera *widget* — only this camera widget is behaving differently from any other widget – lock screen or otherwise.

Once you slide to it the *widget* zoom to full screen and from that onwards behalves like an App. The lock screen camera has rich controls which would be close to impossible to implement using the confines of [`android.widget.RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html).

Here my two questions:

1. How does this actually work?
2. Can it be replicated by normal applications (or is it a feature only available to system applications)?

Comment: "How does this actually work?" -- presumably it is implemented as part of the lock screen itself. "Can it be replicated my normal applications" -- only if you roll your own ROM mod to replace the system lock screen. This is really no different than the various "hey, manufacturer X's home screen has this 'widget' that can do Y -- clearly *all* app widgets can do Y!" arguments that have been offered in the past. In those cases, what is presented to the *user* as just another app widget is really a feature of the home screen.